# How do I know what project revision I'm using in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git

I haven't been able to find this anywhere.  I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue in Eclipse (note: I'm new to Eclipse; I've been using Visual Studio for years).  I need to revert to a project revision, and I want to make sure of what revision I'm currently in.

I have not been able to find this ANYWHERE.  I look at the History, but it only tells me the revision history; it does NOT tell me where I currently AM.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

If it matters, I'm using a Git repository.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: try right-click on file or source code explicitly, then Team -> Show in History

Comment: No.  That doesn't answer my question.  That shows me the revision history.  It doesn't actually tell me where I am.

Comment: To make it clear what I'm looking for: let's say I have revisions HEAD, A, B, and C.  I use "Replace With" to replace it with Revision B, Revision C, whatever.  I want to be able to look up and confirm that I am working with Revision B, Revision C, whatever.  Does this function not exist in Eclipse?

Comment: You can see find where the HEAD tag is in History view. It'll show you where you are now. Also every Eclipse project has information about the repo, current branch and each state relatively to origin near its name in Package Explorer view.
If you do just Replace With, it doesn't change your "git position". You're still at the same place, the same commit, branch, revision etc... Imagine that after this "Replace with" revision C you change some file - what do you want then Eclipse to show. Revision C ? - No! Because it already differes. Info you want is useless. Git gives you everything.